# Placement of return statement in a method with finally block

Tags: java, return, finally

I have a simple doubt. In the following two codes, in first `return` statement is placed inside a `finally` block

```
public int method1(){
    try{
        // Some Stuff
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And in second `return` statement is placed as normal

```
public int method1(){
    try{
         // Some Stuff
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally{

    }
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any difference between these two? And which can be used as better option? why?

Comment: You should never have a return statement inside of a finally block. This can over-write things that were done in the try block, and can lead to really convoluted logic.

Comment: Anything that is returned in the finally block will actually override any exception or returned value that is inside the try/catch block.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not a good practice to have "return" in a finally block. The `finally` block can be executed due to two reasons:

(a) An exception was thrown by the `try` block (and not caught by `catch` block) - in this case the method will have no return value so a `return something` statement in the finally block will have no effect.

(b) the `try` block completed normally. If that block ends with a `return something` then you the code is a bit confusing to the reader, as there are now two return statements that are relevant and it is not clear which should take precedence over the other.

Comment: It is **always** bad practice.

Comment: *(a) ... in this case the method will have no return value* - I hope you mean an exception that wasnt catched in the `catch` branch.